# display image in detail view with one to many reation yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables with one-to-many relation,

This code will display the path not image. how to display image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
[
    'attribute'=>'photo',
    'value'=>$model->photo,
    'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way is setting the **image** format of this column:

```
    [
             'attribute'=>'photo',
             'format' => 'image',
             'value'=>'path/to/image',
    ],
```